# Dependency injection of cxf-bean / client in a grails service doesn't work - maybe because it's configured in my plugins config.groovy?

Tags: grails, groovy, cxf, grails-plugin, grails-2.0

I'm working on a payment plugin for the grails framework. I'm using a payment provider which gives me a SOAP API (WSDL) and I need a cxf-client to communicate with the webservice.

I installed https://github.com/ctoestreich/cxf-client (cxf-client plugin) in my grails plugin project (2.2) and want to use the cxf-client I added to my config.groovy in a grails service.

In the Service Class I just added

```
RecurringPortType recurringPaymentClient
```

I don't start the plugin project directly, instead i included it in my mainproject where I use some methods of the plugins service (also autowired into my mainproject).

After using the autowired plugin service (which works) I get a nullpointer exception using a method which uses the autowired cxf-client in the plugins service class. The cxf-client bean reuccringPaymentClient is null.

But why? Do I have to include the cxf-client configuration also into my mainprojects config.groovy? Or is there a solution my mainproject can merge or also use the config.groovy of my new plugin? At this time the cxf-configuration is placed in the plugins config.groovy - Maybe that's the problem?

Using

```
RecurringPortType recurringPaymentClient = ApplicationHolder.application.mainContext.getBean("recurringPaymentClient")
```

as described in cxf-client documentation didn't help.

Answer (score 1):

The `Config.groovy` file in a plugin only applies when the plugin is run as a standalone application itself.  It is not read when the plugin is used in another application.  A trick I've seen some plugins use (and which I have stolen for one of my own plugins) is to manipulate the configuration in the plugin descriptor's `doWithSpring`, which is usually early enough to have the required effect.  In your case you'd have to make your plugin `loadBefore` the `cxf-client` plugin to ensure that your `doWithSpring` (creating the config) happens before that of `cxf-client` (which is where the settings will be used).

```
class MyCleverGrailsPlugin {
  def version = "0.1-SNAPSHOT"

  def loadBefore = ['cxfClient']

  def doWithSpring = {
    application.config.cxf.client.recurringPaymentClient.clientInterface = com.example.MyClientPortType
    // etc. etc.
  }
}
```

Or you can use `ConfigSlurper` by hand

```
def doWithSpring = {
  ConfigObject pluginConf = new ConfigSlurper(Environment.current.name).parse(com.example.MyPluginDefaultConfig)
  application.config.cxf = pluginConf.cxf.merge(application.config.cxf)
}
```

This loads a `Config.groovy`-style script from the plugin's `src/groovy/com/example/MyPluginDefaultConfig.groovy`, and merges the `cxf` section of that config into the `cxf` section of the main application's configuration, with settings in the app overriding the defaults supplied by the plugin.

Comment: What if the user needs another cxf-client instance for some other purposes in his project? In this case, the ConfigSlurper would be better because it does a merge, am i right?

Comment: @whitenexx both cases do a merge - assigning to `application.config.cxf.client.recurringPaymentClient` won't affect any other `cxf.client.somethingElse` settings. But it would mean the plugin overrides explicit settings in the app for `recurringPaymentClient`, the reverse of the ConfigSlurper approach.

Comment: I suppose a hybrid would be to create a `new ConfigObject()`, set up the plugin settings directly in there and then `merge` it with the app config like I do with the slurper approach.